# Al editar producto se carguen los selects dependientes, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy en la edición del producto y me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

Cuando añado un producto, tengo un select en el que cuando selecciono la categoría donde quiero meter el producto, se me carga otro select con las subcategorias que tiene esa categoría. Hasta ahí bien, pero a la hora de editar el producto no se como hacerlo.

**Así se me carga el valor de categoría, que tiene este producto**

```
<select class="form-control formNuevo" name="categoria" id="categoria">
    <option value=""> Selecciona una categoría </option>
       @foreach ($categorias as $cat)
         <option value="{{ $cat->amigable }}" {{ ( $cat->amigable == $productos->categoria) ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{ $cat->nombre }} </option>
       @endforeach   
</select>
```

**Select subcategoria**

```
<select class="form-control formNuevo" name="subcategoria" id='subcategoria'>
   // lo tengo vacio porque si hago lo mismo como en el de categoría,
      si que me muestra la subcategoria que tiene el producto, pero si decido 
      cambiarla sin cambiar la categoría, pues me salen todas las subcategorias.
</select>
```

**Así saco las subcategorias**

```
$('#categoria').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var categoria = e.target.value;
        
        $.get('../select_category/' + categoria,function(data) {
        
        $('#subcategoria').empty();
        
        $.each(data, function(fetch, subCate){
            console.log(data);
            for(i = 0; i < subCate.length; i++){
            $('#subcategoria').append('<option value="'+ subCate[i].sAmigable +'">'+ subCate[i].nombre +'</option>');
            }
        })
     })
    });
```

**Controller, para sacar las subcategorias**

```
 public function sacaSub($categoria)
    {
        $subCate = Subcategoria::where('categoria', $categoria)->get();
        return with(["subCate" => $subCate]);
    }
```

**Controller para la vista de editar producto**

```
public function editarProducto($id)
    { 
        $productos = Producto::findOrfail($id);
        $brands = Brand::get();
        $categorias = Categoria::get();
        $subcategorias = Subcategoria::get();
        return view("admin.edit_producto")->with(["productos" => $productos,
                                                  "brands" => $brands,
                                                  "categorias" => $categorias,
                                                  "subcategorias" => $subcategorias]);
    }
```

Al final lo que necesito es que me salga la categoría y la subcategoria que tiene el producto, pero si decido cambiar directamente la subcategoria, solo me muestre las subcategorias que tiene esa categoría.

Espero haberme explicado bien, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer es enviar la lista de las subcategorias pertenecientes a la categoria del producto en el controlador:

```
public function editarProducto($id)
    { 
        $productos = Producto::findOrfail($id);
        $brands = Brand::get();
        $categorias = Categoria::get();
        $subcategorias = Subcategoria::where('categoria', $productos->categoria)->get();
        return view("admin.edit_producto")->with(["productos" => $productos,
                                                  "brands" => $brands,
                                                  "categorias" => $categorias,
                                                  "subcategorias" => $subcategorias]);
    }
```

de esta forma puedes cargar el select solo con las subcategorias del producto

Comment: Estupendo funciona perfectamente! Gracias y bienvenida @rootsmina